# Sharing variables across multi level scopes in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Currently I am building a couple of neural networks in a scope and I want to access those networks from another scope.

I have tried passing the scopes but as mentioned in few other answers on stack overflow but none of that works. For example

```
def mlp_model(input, num_outputs, scope, reuse=False, num_units=64, rnn_cell=None):
    # This model takes as input an observation and returns values of all actions
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=reuse):
        out = input
        out = layers.dense(out, units=num_units, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        out = layers.dense(out, units=num_units, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        out = layers.dense(out, units=num_outputs, activation=None)
        return out

input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 64), name="input")

with tf.variable_scope("agent_0") as agent_scope:
    q_func= mlp_model(input_placeholder, 2, "q_func", num_units=64)

with tf.variable_scope("agent_1"):
    with tf.variable_scope(agent_scope, reuse=True):
        q_func_2=mlp_model(input_placeholder, 2, "q_func", num_units=64, reuse=True)
```

when I see the name of q_func it says "agent_0/q_func/dense_2/BiasAdd:0"
and when I see the name of q_func_2 it says "agent_1/agent_0/q_func/dense_2/BiasAdd:0"

I want to figure out how to do q_func == q_func_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently, from the surface, these both tensors look different, they are same under the hood. To verify this, I trained "q_func" only on a simple regression task, the values from "q_func_2" updates as well.